# Configure LFD to not block emails for failed login attempts

Tags: firewall, cpanel, whm

Is it possible to configure LFD in ConfigServer Security & Firewall for cPanels WHM to **not** block failed logins for e-mails? My legitimate users are being blocked more than hack attempts for e-mail accounts.

I've tried googling this but cannot find anything, and don't want to disable LFD entirely as I still want it to block all other types of failed login attempts.

Is there a configuration file that controls what LFD blocks for that can tell it not to block for e-mails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking in the configuration for something else I stumbled across the answer for this and thought I would leave the answer for someone else, should they ever need it. To change this modify the CSF config file and search for `LF_SMTPAUTH`. You can set this to 0 to disable it, or increase the number before a ban kicks in. You can also change `LF_SMTPAUTH_PERM` from 1 to a larger number to make it a temporary permanent ban for that number of seconds. I changed it to 20 attempts and 1800 (30 minutes).

Comment: would you mind going into more detail?  i am having this exact same problem.  where is the CSF login file?

Comment: @tonygil it's the CSF config file, not login file. Go to CSF in WHM and then under **csf - ConfigServer Firewall** the first button is *Firewall Configuration*, it's in there.

Comment: i only have QUICK ALLOW and SEARCH FOR IP enabled.  probably some environmental setting (the physical server is not "mine"). but i did send your answer along to support and am trying to get them to implement the changes i need, now that you have pointed the direction.  tks, UPVOTED :)